# Images not cache in memory with Univeral Image Loader

Tags: android

I am using Universal image loader to load images from the url. but images are not getting stored in the cache after loading. can anyone help? this is the code

```
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.no_pic)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_pic)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.no_pic).cacheInMemory(true)
            .considerExifParams(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            c).threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
            .writeDebugLogs().build();
    // if (!imageLoader.isInited()) {
    imageLoader.init(config);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use cache on disk instead of cache on memory